# Async .net web api sometime does not return any result with angularjs call by passing same id parameter

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, async-await

Async .net  web api sometime does not return any result with angularjs call.
May be due to some problem with my asynchronous code handling at UI end.Can anyone help to fix this up?

**Below is my C# web api code :-**

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("GetTotalUsersData")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetTotalUsersData(int schoolID)
{
    var result = await _analytics.GetTotalUsersData(schoolID);
    return Ok(result);
}
```

**It's part of _analytics**

```
public async Task<RegisteredUsers> GetTotalUsersData(int schoolID)
{
    try
    {
        var users = await _unitOfWork.Repository<User>().GetAllAsync(s => s.School_ID == schoolID);
        return new RegisteredUsers
        {   
            TotalRegisteredUser = users.Where(s => s.UserRole_ID != (byte?)StaticValues.RoleType.SuperAdmin).Count(),
            TotalStudents = users.Where(s => s.UserRole_ID == (byte?)StaticValues.RoleType.STUDENT).Count(),
            TotalGuardian = users.Where(s => s.UserRole_ID == (byte?)StaticValues.RoleType.GUARDIAN).Count(),
            TotalStaff = users.Where(s => s.UserRole_ID == (byte?)StaticValues.RoleType.STAFF|| s.UserRole_ID == (byte?)StaticValues.RoleType.Account || s.UserRole_ID == (byte?)StaticValues.RoleType.Admin).Count(),
        };
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { logger.Log(ex); }
    return null;
}
```

**Angular Code to call above api**

```
  var _totalUsers = function () {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http.get(serviceBase + 'api/Dashbord/GetTotalUsersData', { params: { schoolId: authData().schoolId } }).success(function (response) {
        deferred.resolve(response);
    }).error(function (err, status) {
        deferred.reject(err);
    });
    return deferred.promise;
};

   dashboardServiceFactory.totalUsers = _totalUsers;
 return dashboardServiceFactory;
}]);
```

Async method returns back to it's caller and doesn't come again to get back awaitable results.

sometime it's works fine but in some cases it skips my c# code without saying anything.

Logs have the following error

> {"A second operation started on this context before a previous
>   asynchronous operation completed. Use 'await' to ensure that any
>   asynchronous operations have completed before calling another method
>   on this context. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread
>   safe."}

Comment: Your code looks fine to me on front-end/API. Perhaps you're sometimes calling your API with an invalid `schoolId`? Or maybe your API is timing out on a large query?

Comment: Nope. school id is correct (every time I am passing a single id). some issue with angular call may be. Not sure.I think angular call does not waiting for the response to get back the result from c# api code.

Answer (score 0):

your problem should be the return null in c#, there should be an exception in the database check your log file. Also you could try a rest plugin for your browser and use that plugin to test the back end (one of many *Restlet Client - DHC*)

Comment: Already tried removing return null as well. and if I test with DHC it works fine  all the time. only making issue with angular call.

Answer (score 0):

Try defensive coding. if no result then the action should return not found.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("GetTotalUsersData")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetTotalUsersData(int schoolID) {
    var result = await _analytics.GetTotalUsersData(schoolID);
    if(result != null)
        return Ok(result);

    return NotFound();
}
```

Comment: Yup.again it says 404 (Not Found) . and sometime woks fine.

Comment: @VivekJoshi, So calling the same id multiple times yields different results? is that what you are trying to say?

Comment: @VivekJoshi then you need to check the error logs to see what is causing the null result. because according to your code it will only return null when there is an exception.

Comment: {"A second operation started on this context before a previous asynchronous operation completed. Use 'await' to ensure that any asynchronous operations have completed before calling another method on this context. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe."} .. Thanks I got it now. Let me investigate. I think it's due to _unitOfWork as I am having parallel async calls in this web page.

Answer (score 0):

The exception message you posted is one that EF gives if you query the same context more than once concurrently.

So, it sounds like `_unitOfWork.Repository<User>()` is returning a context that is *shared* between multiple controller instances, which is a no-no. EF contexts cannot be singletons.

On a side note, you might want to move your `Count` operations into the EF query itself. As it currently stands, the EF query is retrieving everything about all the users in a school - loading all of that data from the DB into memory - and then just returning some counts.